# Apex Code Not Running on Site HomePage

Tags: apex

I have created a site, and using site i have deployed that on salesforce, so that user can use that site without salesforce credentials.

But Apex code does not run on homepage and runs on every other page.

i have checked the functionality through inspect element tool, and it displays that no apex code is rendered.

Does anyone knows what is the issue?
please help me out of this.

Thanks in Advance.

Please Refer to My site, u ll find problem. 
https://shoppers-developer-edition.ap2.force.com/ShopNow/HomePage

the Problem is in the slider.
=== code for controller=====

public class navMenuContoller {

```
public List<Offer__c> offerList = new List<Offer__c>();
public List<Offer__c> tempofferList = new List<Offer__c>();
public List<Offer__c> getOfferList() {
    tempofferList = [Select Name, Discount__c, Start_Date__c, End_Date__c, Image__c from Offer__c];
    for(Offer__c o:tempofferList ){
       if((o.Start_Date__c<Date.today()&&o.End_Date__c>Date.today())||Date.today().isSameDay(o.Start_Date__c)||Date.today().isSameDay(o.End_Date__c))
        {
            offerList.add(o);
        }
    }
    return offerList;
}
```

}

=== code for slider ====

```
<apex:repeat value="{!offerList}" var="ol">
<li>
      <apex:outputLink value="/ShopNow/showProducts?offerName={!ol.Name}" >
            <apex:image url="{!ol.Image__c}"/>
      </apex:outputLink>
</li>
  </apex:repeat>
```

Comment: Please provide code for the page and controller class for us to understand your problem.

Comment: What are you currently doing when you click on next icon for deals of day?

Comment: hey abbas i am new to this portal, donno how to attach such long code...

Comment: @kiran- deal of the day is static part, it goes to that product's page.

Comment: abbas i have attached the code please review it...

Comment: Here's a link which could be helpful:

http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/15501/accessing-an-image-from-sites-stored-in-a-rich-text-area-field

Answer (score 0):

Check with the settings for Rich-text area field :- whether they are visible to the user

Here's a link which might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415552/rich-text-area-image-in-salesforce-site